# ng-transclude not working in template AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

Sorry, if something stupid I am missing here, but I really tried various combos to make this code work, but no luck.

I am learning `directive` in `AngularjS` from `Recipes with AngularJS` but stuck at this code -

https://github.com/fdietz/recipes-with-angular-js-examples/tree/master/chapter3/recipe4

I believe it should print **Heading** before **Hello World** `p` text. but its not coming. Let me know what I am missing in my code -

[PLNKR CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/4HW3vCP6Lksi2xPrC9XO?p=preview)

Code as a Whole -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Directive Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

        myApp.directive("myWidget", function(){
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                transclude: true,
                template: "<div ng-transclude><h3>Heading</h3></div>"
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-widget>
        <p>Hello World!!</p>
    </my-widget>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check the first "h3" before "div"

```
template: "<h3>Heading</h3><div ng-transclude></div>"
```

Comment: Why I need to change as the recipe is placing h3 in div and its code is working too, but not in a single file ?

Comment: the content is added inside the ng-transclude. you can wrapped it with another <div> if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you need to change the recipe is because Angular changed how transclusion works between v1.0 and v1.2.

With change [eed299a3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eed299a31b5a6dd0363133c5f9271bf33d090c94), Angular now "clears the translusion point before transcluding."

If you load v1.0 (which is what the github repository uses), you will see "Heading".  With v1.2, you won't see "Heading", unless you modify the template the way @Noypi explained.